# Dynamic code for storing multiple values

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a polygon which has been plotted for a county using Google Maps iOS SDK.

For each county, there are multiple latitude and longitude so we can plot it.

The code is for 1 Country. Is there a way where I can make it for multiple countries?

So, the structure would be:

```
County 1 - 

lat       long
32.4757   -86.41182
31.7557   -88.41482
32.4357   -87.65335

County 2 - 

lat       long
42.4757   -96.41182
41.7557   -98.41482
42.4357   -97.65335

County 3 - 

lat       long
52.4757   -76.41182
51.7557   -78.41482
52.4357   -77.65335
```

Code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func loadView() {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.0902, longitude: -95.7129, zoom: 3.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    view = mapView


    struct county {
        let lat: CLLocationDegrees
        let long: CLLocationDegrees
    }

    let counties = [
        county(lat: 32.4757, long: -86.41182),
        county(lat: 32.46599, long: -86.41177),
        county(lat: 32.45054, long: -86.41167),
        county(lat: 32.44245, long: -86.41157),
        county(lat: 32.43993, long: -86.41154),
        county(lat: 32.42573, long: -86.41138),
        county(lat: 32.42417, long: -86.41135),
        county(lat: 32.42185, long: -86.41128),
        county(lat: 32.41017, long: -86.41117),
        county(lat: 32.40994, long: -86.41117),
        county(lat: 32.4072, long: -86.41615),
        county(lat: 32.40132, long: -86.43178),
        county(lat: 32.40025, long: -86.43926),
        county(lat: 32.40036, long: -86.44653),
        county(lat: 32.40573, long: -86.45876),
        county(lat: 32.40285, long: -86.4612),
        county(lat: 32.38769, long: -86.46247),
        county(lat: 32.37729, long: -86.46356),
        county(lat: 32.37368, long: -86.46836),
        county(lat: 32.37136, long: -86.47092),
        county(lat: 32.36874, long: -86.47306),
        county(lat: 32.36588, long: -86.47476),
        county(lat: 32.36418, long: -86.47777),
        county(lat: 32.36497, long: -86.48023),
        county(lat: 32.36667, long: -86.48342),
        county(lat: 32.36674, long: -86.4871),
        county(lat: 32.36532, long: -86.49047),
        county(lat: 32.36286, long: -86.49265),
        county(lat: 32.36032, long: -86.49263),
        county(lat: 32.35787, long: -86.49181),
        county(lat: 32.35513, long: -86.4908),
        county(lat: 32.35264, long: -86.48994),
        county(lat: 32.34985, long: -86.4899),
        county(lat: 32.34705, long: -86.49071),
        county(lat: 32.34509, long: -86.49308),
        county(lat: 32.34451, long: -86.49637),
        county(lat: 32.34444, long: -86.49677),
        county(lat: 32.34441, long: -86.49697),
        county(lat: 32.34039, long: -86.51978),
        county(lat: 32.36286, long: -86.54242),
        county(lat: 32.37296, long: -86.56658),
        county(lat: 32.36775, long: -86.58826),
        county(lat: 32.38072, long: -86.61646),
        county(lat: 32.40307, long: -86.61548),
        county(lat: 32.40372, long: -86.62671),
        county(lat: 32.40055, long: -86.64956),
        county(lat: 32.37904, long: -86.65426),
        county(lat: 32.36937, long: -86.66333),
        county(lat: 32.35659, long: -86.67726),
        county(lat: 32.35356, long: -86.68276),
        county(lat: 32.35677, long: -86.69448),
        county(lat: 32.36186, long: -86.71309),
        county(lat: 32.36921, long: -86.71624),
        county(lat: 32.3884, long: -86.71982),
        county(lat: 32.40129, long: -86.71721),
        county(lat: 32.40061, long: -86.73083),
        county(lat: 32.38914, long: -86.75543),
        county(lat: 32.39047, long: -86.78214),
        county(lat: 32.37337, long: -86.78238),
        county(lat: 32.32449, long: -86.7843),
        county(lat: 32.30819, long: -86.80352),
        county(lat: 32.3184, long: -86.82039),
        county(lat: 32.3402, long: -86.81563),
        county(lat: 32.3408, long: -86.81491),
        county(lat: 32.34299, long: -86.81229),
        county(lat: 32.36582, long: -86.81294),
        county(lat: 32.38605, long: -86.8318),
        county(lat: 32.41849, long: -86.8411),
        county(lat: 32.4304, long: -86.83652),
        county(lat: 32.43893, long: -86.85357),
        county(lat: 32.43869, long: -86.86242),
        county(lat: 32.44592, long: -86.86415),
        county(lat: 32.4606, long: -86.86997),
        county(lat: 32.47188, long: -86.87364),
        county(lat: 32.48191, long: -86.88497),
        county(lat: 32.48886, long: -86.88087),
        county(lat: 32.49656, long: -86.88465),
        county(lat: 32.5124, long: -86.89084),
        county(lat: 32.52588, long: -86.89979),
        county(lat: 32.53685, long: -86.90667),
        county(lat: 32.54915, long: -86.90521),
        county(lat: 32.55933, long: -86.90023),
        county(lat: 32.57819, long: -86.89905),
        county(lat: 32.59242, long: -86.90385),
        county(lat: 32.60835, long: -86.90759),
        county(lat: 32.62085, long: -86.91163),
        county(lat: 32.63178, long: -86.9119),
        county(lat: 32.64452, long: -86.9185),
        county(lat: 32.65322, long: -86.91827),
        county(lat: 32.66411, long: -86.91767),
        county(lat: 32.66417, long: -86.91759),
        county(lat: 32.66417, long: -86.91757),
        county(lat: 32.66425, long: -86.91241),
        county(lat: 32.66343, long: -86.8929),
        county(lat: 32.66258, long: -86.87358),
        county(lat: 32.66137, long: -86.84557),
        county(lat: 32.66082, long: -86.83382),
        county(lat: 32.66016, long: -86.81764),
        county(lat: 32.66017, long: -86.81319),
        county(lat: 32.66052, long: -86.78767),
        county(lat: 32.66098, long: -86.74998),
        county(lat: 32.66159, long: -86.72508),
        county(lat: 32.66738, long: -86.71349),
        county(lat: 32.70574, long: -86.71257),
        county(lat: 32.70609, long: -86.66704),
        county(lat: 32.70633, long: -86.63189),
        county(lat: 32.70629, long: -86.61778),
        county(lat: 32.70632, long: -86.60783),
        county(lat: 32.70653, long: -86.59515),
        county(lat: 32.70678, long: -86.57015),
        county(lat: 32.70704, long: -86.52944),
        county(lat: 32.7073, long: -86.4963),
        county(lat: 32.7076, long: -86.48468),
        county(lat: 32.70778, long: -86.47197),
        county(lat: 32.70786, long: -86.46803),
        county(lat: 32.70809, long: -86.45035),
        county(lat: 32.70747, long: -86.41583),
        county(lat: 32.70739, long: -86.41312),
        county(lat: 32.67818, long: -86.413),
        county(lat: 32.67406, long: -86.41298),
        county(lat: 32.61636, long: -86.41261),
        county(lat: 32.58942, long: -86.4125),
        county(lat: 32.57816, long: -86.41244),
        county(lat: 32.55023, long: -86.41234),
        county(lat: 32.53344, long: -86.41226),
        county(lat: 32.52876, long: -86.41223),
        county(lat: 32.52668, long: -86.4122),
        county(lat: 32.52082, long: -86.4123),
        county(lat: 32.51273, long: -86.41231),
        county(lat: 32.50446, long: -86.41234),
        county(lat: 32.50006, long: -86.4122),
        county(lat: 32.49626, long: -86.41212),
        county(lat: 32.49065, long: -86.41197),
        county(lat: 32.48577, long: -86.41197),
        county(lat: 32.48112, long: -86.41187),
    ]
    let rect = GMSMutablePath()
    for county in counties {
        rect.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: county.lat, longitude: county.long))
    }
    // Create the polygon, and assign it to the map.
    let polygon = GMSPolygon(path: rect)
    polygon.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05);
    polygon.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    polygon.strokeWidth = 2
    polygon.map = mapView

}
}
```

Comment: Of course there's a way. An array of arrays? An array of dictionaries? An array of some custom struct? A dictionary of county name - array pairs? A dictionary of county name - custom struct pairs? What's the problem here? Pick one or think of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can try like this create on `Location` struct that store lat-long and change Country `struct` that will store country name and CountryLocation array.

```
struct CountryLocation {
    let lat: CLLocationDegrees
    let long: CLLocationDegrees
}

struct Country {
    var name: String
    var locations = [CountryLocation]()
}
```

Now create array of country and all object of it will store locations for that specific country.

**Option 2**

You can use `Dictionary` that contain key as Country name and value as your Array of your Country for that you just need to create the dictionary no need to change any thing in your `struct`.

```
var countries = [String: [Country]]()
```

**Edit:** To store object for option 1 try like this.

```
var countries = [Country(name:"Ind",locations:[CountryLocation(lat:22.663696,long:87.746803),CountryLocation(lat:22.542061,long:88.318954)],
                 Country(name:"UK",locations:[CountryLocation(lat:52.412811,long:-1.778197),CountryLocation(lat:51.481583,long:-3.179090),CountryLocation(lat:50.768036,long:0.290472)]
                ]
```

Comment: Why define the `Location` struct? There is already `CLLocationCoordinate2D` which the OP needs to use already.

Comment: How can I declare my county? county(name: "Alabama County", locations: [Location.lat: 2.4757, Location.long: -86.41182]) gives me error.

Comment: check the edited answer also locations is array of `CountryLocations`

Comment: Can you give me example of how to insert data in Country struct?

Comment: Also, how to structure the for loop so I can access 1 county at a time with each of their lat, long?

Comment: Check edited answer and for loop that is depended on your data.